# listbox loads more data than it should

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a  listbox on a form which loads using the following code, which is called directly from the form_load event only once.

```
Private Sub LoadList()

  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim condition As String

  Set db = CurrentDb

  condition = " WHERE Schedule_ID = " & ScheduleID

  strSQL = "SELECT Shifts.Shift_ID, Shifts.Start_Date_Time, Shifts.End_Date_Time, Locations.Location_Name FROM Shifts, Locations " & _
"WHERE Schedule_ID = " & ScheduleID & " AND Locations.Location_ID = Shifts.Location ORDER BY Start_Date_Time"

  'Set Recordset Query
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  RecCount = recordCount("Shifts", condition)
  Me.lblCount.Caption = "Shift Count: " & RecCount

  rs.MoveFirst
  For i = 0 To RecCount - 1
    Me.lstShifts.AddItem rs!Shift_ID & ";" & rs!Start_Date_Time & " TO " & rs!End_Date_Time & " AT " & rs!Location_Name
    rs.MoveNext
  Next i

  'Close Connections and Reset Variables
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

  listdirty = False
End Sub
```

There are only ten records in the database and yet the listbox loads the data three times (30 in all). I stepped through the code and on the RecCount variable it gets initialized properly to ten and the for loop iterates ten times as expected.  This LoadList sub doesn't get called more than once, so I don't understand why the records are showing up in the listbox multiple times. Any ideas?

Comment: Add `Debug.Print strSQL`, run the code, copy the `SELECT` statement text from the Immediate window and paste it into SQL View of a new query in the query designer.  When you run that query, how many rows does it return?

Comment: Wow, that worked.  I didn't know you could form an SQL query this way.  Incidentally I discovered what was causing the duplication of records in the listbox.  When I looked at the RowSource property of the listbox it was full of existing data.  How that got there I don't know.  Certainly your solution is much better.  Thanks

Comment: Probably you saved the form design with a non-empty value list for the list box's `RowSource`.  But queries be powerful ... so you should be able to scale back `LoadList()` to only a couple lines of code.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time your `LoadList()` procedure is called, it adds rows to the list box.  Since the list box contains 30 rows despite the source recordset containing only 10, either `LoadList()` is called 3 times or you're saving the form with a non-empty value list and adding 10 more rows at each *Form Load*.

You could avoid that problem by emptying out the `RowSource` value list before the loop where you do `AddItem` ...

```vb
rs.MoveFirst
Me.lstShifts.RowSource = vbNullString ' make sure value list starts empty
For i = 0 To RecCount - 1
    Me.lstShifts.AddItem rs!Shift_ID & ";" & rs!Start_Date_Time & " TO " & rs!End_Date_Time & " AT " & rs!Location_Name
    rs.MoveNext
Next i
```

However you have a query which is almost what you want the list box to display.  It should be simpler to revise that query and use it as the list box `RowSource`:

1. Change the list box's `RowSourceType` property from *"Value List"* to *"Table/Query"*.
2. Make sure you have the list box's column count property set to 2.
3. In your `LoadList()` procedure, revise the query field list to `SELECT Shifts.Shift_ID, Shifts.Start_Date_Time & ' TO ' & Shifts.End_Date_Time & ' AT ' & Locations.Location_Name`
4. Finally, assign the updated query to the list box's `RowSource` property: `Me.lstShifts.RowSource = strSQL`